# $(this).parents("p").append("hello"); not matching the expected element

Tags: jquery

This is for a comment/reply system. The following code displays the main comments and replies to the comments. The jQuery code is supposed to select the (paragraph `id="test"`) element and append the message as a reply message when the reply button is clicked.

jQuery `$(this).parents("p").append("hello");` is not working. I've tried using `closest("p")` and `find("p")` but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
<div class='box'>
    <?php 
        // Comments from database code goes here
    ?>
</div>

<div class="feedback">
    <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo "".$row['Username'].":&nbsp";echo $row['replyormsg'];
        }
    ?> 
    <p id="test"><p>                                       
</div>

<div class="replymsg">
    <!-- Reply Form/Textbox -->
    <form class=".replyform">   
        <textarea class="replytext" ></textarea>
        <button class="replybutton" data-value="<?php echo $commentid; ?>">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".replybutton").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data("value");
        var replytext = $(this).prev().val();
        $(this).parents("p").append("hello"); 
        $("textarea").val(""); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Because, I don't see any ancestor `p` element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.replyButton` element has no parent `p` element, hence why the `parents('p')` selector returns nothing. Assuming you're looking for the `p` element within `.feedback` you should use this:

```
$('.feedback p').append("hello");
```

Assuming that you were using DOM traversal because this block of HTML is repeated, you firstly should remove the `id="test"` from the `p` (as it will be repeated and therefore invalid). You can then traverse to the nearest `.feedback p` from the clicked `.replyButton`, using this:

```
$(this).closest('.replymsg').prev('.feedback').find('p').text('hello');
```

Comment: Then why not `$('#test').append('Hello')`

Comment: @Tushar because using DOM traversal generally means that you're looking to find an element in a repeated block of code, where `id` would end up being repeated and hence invalid.

Comment: The reply messages are in a while loop,where the reply message is attached to the given comment using a specified Id. That is why I need to use $(this) so I am repliying to a specific comment. If I use $('.feedback') it appends to all the div's on the page with all comments.

Comment: Thanks for the help,I got it with your help but had to change to:

Comment: $(this).parents('.replymsg').prev('.feedback').find('p[id=test]').text('hello');

Comment: `closest()` would be better in your case as it will stop at the first match. Also, as I stated, you should remove the `id` attribute from the `p` element otherwise your page will be invalid.

Comment: if i dont use id it re-writes all the peplies.I've tested it on Wamp.

Comment: In the feedback div I was using the p element ,I just removed it for this post to make the code appear cleaner.Thanks Rory!